# Is it possible to "autowire" the bean definition into a bean?

Tags: spring, debugging

For debugging purposes, I would like to do this:

```
@Autowired
private BeanDefinition myBeanDefinition;
```

i.e. after the factory has created the bean, it should wire the bean definition into it so I can easily see where it came from during debugging.

Or maybe there is another way to see at runtime where a bean was defined?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `BeanPostProcessor`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class AutowireBeanDefinitionPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization( Object bean, String beanName ) throws BeansException {

        if( bean instanceof BeanDefinitionAware ) {
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory = ( (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext ).getBeanFactory();
            BeanDefinition bd = factory.getBeanDefinition( beanName );

            ( (BeanDefinitionAware) bean ).setBeanDefinition( bd );
        }

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization( Object bean, String beanName ) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Make your beans implement `BeanDefinitionAware`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;

public interface BeanDefinitionAware {
    void setBeanDefinition( BeanDefinition beanDefinition );
}
```

and you can store the definition in a field.